# perl - disk name on Linux

Tags: perl

What module would you recommend to get a disk name on Linux? I've done some search on CPAN but all modules I've found are too old. In Bash I can use something like:

```
disk_name=$(df |grep -w '/'|awk '{print $1}'|cut -d/ -f3)
echo $disk_name
sda6
```

Please help me to understand how to do same in Perl.
Thanks.

Comment: They work, but some people here advised me not to use modules which are not supported any longer and have many bugs reported.

Comment: First, df doesn't return disk names.  Rather it reports the mount points for mounted file systems.  Using grep, awk and cut in a pipeline is a process waste!  Awk can do everything you show, as certainly can Perl.

Comment: That is why I am trying to learn how to do same in Perl )

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific about `df` output you are using. None of the ones I tried on my system work the way your command suggests. More specifically, your `grep` will ONLY pick where root is mounted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "proper" way to list mounted disks on Linux is through the `getmntent()` system call, which can be accessed from Perl using the [Quota](http://search.cpan.org/~tomzo/Quota/) module:

```
use Quota;

Quota::setmntent();
while (my ($dev, $path, $type, $opts) = Quota::getmntent()) {
    print "The root device is $dev.\n"  if $path eq "/";
}
Quota::endmntent();
```

As a bonus, using the Quota module to list device mount points should be fairly portable to other Unixish systems, which parsing various system files or the output of `df` may not be.  Unfortunately, this seemingly basic module is not included in the standard Perl distribution, so you have to get it from CPAN (or from your distro's package repository — for example, Debian / Ubuntu have the [libquota-perl](http://packages.debian.org/libquota-perl) package).

---

Ps. Simply splitting the device name on `/` and taking the third element (as your `cut` command does) is *not* a safe way to turn, say, `/dev/sdb1` into `sdb1`.  Some issues with it are that:

1. Not all block devices *have* to live under `/dev` — it's really just a convention.
2. Even if the device file *is* under `/dev`, it might be in a subdirectory of it.  For example, my root filesystem is on the device `/dev/disk/by-uuid/627f8512-f037-4c6c-9892-6130090c0e0f`.
3. Sometimes, the device name might not even be an actual filesystem path: for example, virtual or in-memory filesystems such as `tmpfs` are often mounted with the device name `none`, but it's possible to use *any* device name with them.

If you do want to get rid of the `/dev/` part, I'd suggest a conservative approach using a regexp, for example like this:

```
if ($dev =~ m(^/dev/(.*)$)s) {
    print "The directory $path is mounted from device $1 under /dev.\n";
} else {
    print "The directory $path is not mounted from a device under /dev.\n"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is not the disk name but the device name of the block device representing the partition mounted at root (/).  On a regular computer it would normally be something like `/dev/sdXN` or `/dev/hdXN` with X being the disk number (primary hard drive is usually A, secondary is B, etc.) and N is the partition number on that device.

Provided you're always running on a unix system, you can try reading /etc/mtab file, which lists all mounted partitions, or the special file `/proc/mounts`, which pretty much does the same.  You'll need to parse it afterwards to find the one you need and get the device name from it.

Alternatively, you can just run `df` as a process and get its input into perl, something like

```
open(DF, "df|");
@mount_points = <DF>;
close(DF);
```

and then iterate over the data to find what you need.  I'm not aware of any modules of the top of my head that would do the job for you, but the code seems pretty simple to me anyway.

P.S. Note that Max OS X, while being a derivative of BSD, doesn't have the same file structure and therefore this approach wouldn't work.  On Mac OS X, you can read file `/etc/fstab.hd`, which contains similar info but in a slightly different format.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do just what you are doing in the question

```
df / | perl -ne 'm"^/\w+/(\w+)";print "$1\n" if defined $1;'
```

but using a CPAN library to do it is probably better.